# read data on elasticsearch cluster using spark and querystringquery

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I want to read bulk data on ES cluster. Using the scroll api, I can read it easily till the scroll doesnt return a new id. Following is my implementation:

```
while(searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0){
        SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId);
        scrollRequest.scroll(scroll);
        searchResponse = client.searchScroll(scrollRequest);
        scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
        searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
        for(SearchHit s: searchHits){
            String source = s.getSourceAsString();
            System.out.println(source);
        }
    }
```

I use a querybuilder to create a query from a query-string-query like this:

```
QueryStringQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("(a AND (b OR c OR d OR e))");
```

Considering that eshadoop has no such feature, but basically utilizes the same concept where the search is divided across multiple partitions/shards, I simply translated the code into the spark connector:

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    .config("fs
    .s3n.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.access.key", ""))
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.secret.key",""))
        .config("es.nodes", "my aws cluster name")
        .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .master("local[*]")
        .getOrCreate()
```

I am running into a host of errors here. First error i get is while connecting to cluster:

```
18/03/12 10:31:40 INFO HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception 
(java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
18/03/12 10:31:40 INFO HttpMethodDirector: Retrying request
```

If this is solved, I do not know how to proceed and add a querystringquery to the spark client. Please someone help me with how to resolve the I/O error and then add a QSQ query.

P.S.: On a side note, in the spark app, is it advisable to use the normal scroll api which will read bulk of data and load it into the rdd?

Comment: Is there any update on this question?  I am working on a similar task, thanks!

Comment: @RuxiZhang yes. So the reason es-hadoop wasnt able to onnect directly to the aws es cluster is because it needs a mandatory signed request. If you try and use something like `es-proxy` that should solve your purpose. I have tried and it worked like a charm. Its available on github.